# version control on a deviation of a read-only git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have read-only access to a `project 1` git directory.

I would like to set a git directory that handles the changes and addition of only a few subfolders in the `project 1` and would call it `project 1.2` which is a deviation of `project 1`.

what folder architecture would be best to use at the pull changes from the `project 1` but still keep version control on `project 1.2`

Comment: A submodule or a symlink or something like that? Have you read [ask] and tried searching? If so, what did you find?

Comment: I wouldn't do this via folder structure, do it via an "upstream" remote. See e.g. https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork